# Send events server side with google anlitycs 4 api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website where i need to send some events from server-side using PHP.
any help would be appreciated, i treid all the way on the doc without succes

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4